# Best decision for regression tree

Tags: r, regression, decision-tree, prediction, rpart

Pretend I've created a regression tree:

```
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)
data("mtcars")
fit <- rpart(mpg~., data = mtcars)
prp(fit)
```

Now by looking at the tree I can understand what variables will lead me to the maximum of mpg and to minimum.

But what if I have a big tree? How can I find out what variable values will lead me to the highest result?

Comment: What do you mean by "highest result"?  Best accuracy?  Or are you trying to learn how to read the dendrogram?

Comment: My perfect result is. To make highest possible mpg, cyl ==4 and wt >= 20, or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the highest or lowest,  this will work.    You can get the value of `mpg` at every node using

```
fit$frame$yval
[1] 20.09062 16.64762 13.41429 18.26429 26.66364
```

Every time a node splits, if that node has mpg = M, the two split nodes will have one higher than M and one lower than M. Therefore, both the maximum and minimum will occur at leaves of the tree. So the highest leaf is

```
max(fit$frame$yval)
[1] 26.66364
```

#### Addition

Sorry,  I missed that part of the question.

By using `which.max` we can determine which node is the one with the maximum.

```
which.max(fit$frame$yval)
[1] 5
```

Now we know it is node 5. From there we can use `.list.rules.party` from the `partykit` package to get the relevant rule.   Since `.list.rules.party` is not exported from the package,  we have to specify where the function comes from. 
Also, the function only gives rules for the leaves, so we have to get the rules for the node with the *name* 5, not with the 5th rule.

```
PFit = as.party(fit)
Rules = partykit:::.list.rules.party(PFit)
Rules["5"]
        5 
"cyl < 5"
```

Or you could streamline the whole thing with

```
Rules[as.character(which.max(fit$frame$yval))]
        5 
"cyl < 5"
```

To get the rules for the smallest value

```
Rules[as.character(which.min(fit$frame$yval))]
                       3 
"cyl >= 5 & hp >= 192.5"
```

Comment: Thanks. But how now, knowing the highest node to find out what equations should be. Like cyl == 4 & wt >= 20.

Comment: Adding to answer.